# PHP Remove the Second Record Group Name

Tags: php, mysql, sql

anyone know how to grouping a record with same group but the next row the group name is blank with PHP/MySQL, for example :

Record on the database table :

```
| id | group_title | item     | qty | price
| 1  | G-01        | Mouse    |  1  |   $5
| 2  | G-01        | Keyboard |  1  |   $12
| 3  | G-01        | Keyboard |  1  |   $12
| 4  | G-01        | Cable    |  1  |   $1
| 5  | G-02        | Headset  |  1  |   $20
```

And expected result :

```
| Group | Item Name | Qty | Price/qty | Price Total/item | Price Total/group
| G-01  | Mouse     |  1  | $5        | $5               | $30
|       | Keyboard  |  2  | $12       | $24              | 
|       | Cable     |  1  | $1        | $1               | 
| G-02  | Headset   |  1  | $20       | $20              | $20
```

I have tried to do it for many days, but still not solved. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: why would you like to have a blank group name? How are you suppose to know which group belong the 2nd and 3rd rows? If it's a display requirement, don't display it, but imo it should be in the data rows

Comment: You should consider handling such data display related requirements in the application code (eg: PHP, Java, C++ etc)

Comment: update you question and add  the code you are using an dyour actula result too

Comment: When parsing your array in your PHP loop, just initialise a little place holder so that you can print '' whenever the placeholder value is the same as the current value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a simple **IF** and a **uservar** like this query:

```
SELECT 
    IF(g.gname = @myg, '', @myg:= gname) AS gname,
    g.mytext
FROM grouptab g
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT   @myg:='') AS init
ORDER BY g.gname;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from grouptab;
+----+-------+---------+
| id | gname | mytext  |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | G01   | Name 1  |
|  2 | G01   | Name 2  |
|  3 | G02   | Name 88 |
|  4 | G02   | Name 99 |
|  5 | G01   | Name 4  |
+----+-------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->     IF(g.gname = @myg, '', @myg:= gname) AS gname,
    ->     g.mytext
    -> FROM grouptab g
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT   @myg:='') AS init
    -> ORDER BY g.gname;
+-------+---------+
| gname | mytext  |
+-------+---------+
| G01   | Name 1  |
|       | Name 2  |
|       | Name 4  |
| G02   | Name 88 |
|       | Name 99 |
+-------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: Where application code is available, the above seems like the wrong approach