# Compare to previous row and leave empty, if same value

Tags: mysql

I have the following problem at the moment.

I have a table, where I got the name from, tours for example and I have a subtable with more than 1 row related to the tours, the table journeys.

What I want to get:

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |  Name      |   Subname   |   Info Sub  |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 | Tour 1     | Journey 1   | duration,km |
| 2 |            | Journey 2   | duration,km |
| 3 |            | Journey 3   | duration,km |
| 4 | Tour 2     | Journey 1   | duration,km |
| 5 |            | Journey 2   | duration,km |
| 6 | Tour 3     | Journey 1   | duration,km |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

What I've tried already:

```
SELECT 
if (t.id = @tid,"",(SELECT tourname FROM tours WHERE id = @tid)),
tj.journeyname,
if(@tid != t.id, @tid := t.id,"")
FROM tours t 
JOIN tours_journeys tj ON tj.toursid = t.id ORDER BY t.id
```

It seems that the @tid gets assigned before the selection is done, so the tourname gets printed again in the last row with the same tourname. Would be great, if someone knows how to do this. :)

Comment: If you want to make a table without repetition of one of the names it would be a lot easier to do this in your presentation layer instead of the database layer. Just get the DB to spit out the data and then let your application take care of how it looks to the user.

Comment: yeah but in this case, its not possible to do this, I have to achieve this with the database alone.

Comment: why do you have to do that? Don't you have an application on top of this?

Comment: @P. Lange -  see my answer at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186120/php-remove-the-second-record-group-name/53186561#53186561

Comment: @ADyson we have, but we have no access to it.

Comment: @BerndBuffen the same problem as my query has, it repeats at the last row

Comment: @P. Lange - pls show the result that you want

Comment: @BerndBuffen
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6K3bSDh3r7eg3c2kyZi3hq/1

take a look at this. I have a similar problem, I don't want the gname shown in row 4 again because its still the same like in row 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with a subquery. this sorted the result in the correct order to use the **IF** like this:

```
SELECT  
    IF(result.id = @myg, '', @myg:= result.id) AS gname,
    result.*
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.id,
        tj.journeyName
    FROM tours t
    JOIN tour_journeys tj ON tj.tour_id = t.id
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT   @myg:='') AS init
    ORDER BY t.id, tj.id
) result;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT
    ->     IF(result.id = @myg, '', @myg:= result.id) AS gname,
    ->     result.*
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT
    ->         t.id,
    ->         tj.journeyName
    ->     FROM tours t
    ->     JOIN tour_journeys tj ON tj.tour_id = t.id
    ->     CROSS JOIN ( SELECT   @myg:='') AS init
    ->     ORDER BY t.id, tj.id
    -> ) result;
+-------+------+-------------+
| gname | id   | journeyName |
+-------+------+-------------+
| 1     |    1 | journey 1   |
|       |    1 | journey 2   |
|       |    1 | journey 3   |
|       |    1 | journey 4   |
|       |    1 | journey 5   |
|       |    1 | journey 6   |
| 2     |    2 | journey 1   |
|       |    2 | journey 2   |
+-------+------+-------------+
8 rows in set (0.006 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I've needed. Thank you very much, its working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LAG statement for this (assuming SQL 2012 or greater) and reverse the way you join the tables.

```
SELECT
    tj.id,
    case
        when LAG(tourname) over (order by t.id) = t.tourname then ''
        else t.tourname
    end as tourname,
    journeyname
FROM tours_journeys tj 
    JOIN tours t ON tj.toursid = t.id 
ORDER BY t.id
```

Here, if the tour name in previous row of the resultset matches the current one, we return empty string.

For the first row in the resultset the previous row value will be NULL so this should be fine.

Be sure that the order by for the query and the order by in the lag statement match.